# What kind of verb should be used in order to say that something has increased or created inefficiency?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

What kind of verb should be used in order to say that something has *increased* or *created* inefficiency?

Maybe *generate* or *produce*?

Edit: I'm asking this because *created* or *increased* *inefficiency* sound wrong to me instinctively and when I read them out loud.

Comment: Could you explain what is wrong with “increased” or “created”. Otherwise it’s not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Does your feeling that "created/increased" aren't the best fits here come (at least in part) from a feeling that those two are too positive/not neutral enough to use with a negative notion like "inefficiency"?  If so, maybe "**[cause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cause)** [greater] inefficiency" would be neutral/negative enough to jive better with that negative notion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with other "in-" words where the "in-" means opposite.

..increased invisibility...
.. ineffectiveness ...

There's the alliteration of **in**creased **in**efficiency in juxtiposition with the contrary motion of the two words, one going up while the other goes down?
It does seem a bit tortured, like it can't quite make up its mind.

"**Introduced** inefficiency" doesn't seem to have the same tangled feeling.

Unless you want that implied tension, I would go for the more direct: lowered efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

In a workplace setting saying either *lowered productivity* or *decreased productivity* would be appropriate.  If the change is significant you can also use *killed productivity*.

Answer (score -1):

As ever, more context would lead to better answers.

I don't think "increased inefficiency" is necessarily bad, though it's probably slightly worse than "decrease efficiency" in the same way that "decrease height" is better than "increase shortness."

The problem with words like *create*, *generate*, *produce*, or the one that leapt to my mind, *introduce*, is that everything is always somewhat inefficient.  You can't "create inefficiency" in a process, because that would mean that in a prior state, it would have been perfectly efficient, which is not possible. To be precise, you should only talk about changing the level of efficiency.

However, any of those productive verbs could be used with the related word *inefficienc**ies***, which would be processes, or parts of processes that are inefficient. New inefficiencies can be created, generated, produced, introduced, etc.

You might want to play around with Google Ngram Viewer:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=increase+inefficiency%2Cintroduce+inefficiencies%2Ccreate+inefficiency%2Cdecrease+efficiency%2C+generate+inefficiency&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cincrease%20inefficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintroduce%20inefficiencies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccreate%20inefficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecrease%20efficiency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgenerate%20inefficiency%3B%2Cc0